# implemeneting oauth 1.0a (Server/Provider)

Tags: php, oauth

i am currently developing an api and i wanted to use oauth 1.0a. However i can't seem to find any good reference on how implemenet oauth 1.0a (Server/Provider). Any ideas where i can get such document? or suggestions where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link: http://oauth.net/code/

Go to Section "**PHP**"

There is an [extension to php](http://php.net/oauth) that supports OAuth. It was written by [John Jawed](http://jawed.name/). An example can be found [here](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/oauth/trunk/examples/) and a [walkthrough](http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/50-Using-pecloauth-to-post-to-Twitter.html) is also available. This [pecl package](http://pecl.php.net/package/oauth) is considered the de facto standard by Rasmus Lerdorf.

Comment: I actually used this. however, i can't generate a request_token. It's always giving me "signature_invalid". Currently testing my api using postman. any thoughts on this?